# Alternating series problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

My mind is blanking completely on how to do this one. the base string of numbers i have to pull a series out of is 
$$ \frac{2}{3} -\frac{2}{5} + \frac{2}{7} - \frac{2}{9} + \frac{2}{11} - ...$$
which i found to be
 $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n( \frac{2}{2n+1} )   $$
I have to do an An to Bn, and if Bn is >= 0 and Bn is decreasing it's convergent right?

so i'm thinking my Bn is $$ \frac{2}{2n+1} .$$ ? which Is greater than 0 so I  think that that's Divergent.
Am I on the right track?

Comment: wait no the Bn is (-1)^n+1, so i fixed it. that means my Bn is (2/(2n+1)) so that means it's above 0 so it converges.

Comment: Tibbiticus What do you mean by "I have to do an $An$ to $Bn$"?

Comment: Sorry, i'm just now waking up. I have to look at the An and Bn to where $$sum_{n=1}^\infty An $$ is $$ An = (-1)^n Bn$$ where Bn >= 0

Comment: @Tibbiticus That edit renders the question invalid (namely, you still have the statement "which is less than zero", even though you modified the relevant expression to no longer be negative)

Comment: nevermind i see what you were speaking of. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Alternating Series Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) says that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^ka_k
$$
converges as long as $a_{k+1}\le a_k$ and $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}a_k=0$.

Comparing to the [Leibniz Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80), your series converges to $2-\pi/2$.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's the exact explanation as i was looking for!

Comment: I think i understand these now.